# How can I hide and show chatbot based on a certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The chatbot like this : https://codepen.io/happyforever/pen/BaagjmP

I want to hide and show chatbot based on a certain time

For example :

`08:00-16:00` : show chatbot

`16:00-18:00` : hidden chatbot

How can I do it?

Comment: you can create a interval function which will get the current time and set some variable based on it. Use this variable to show or hide.

Comment: @Saima Haji You mean this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp?

Comment: Better go for doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: @Saima Haji Seems it's the same

Comment: Yup but we should refer docs because they have updated details and they give info of browser support of that particular method. and other sites sometimes have deprecated details.

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000); //put whatever time span you want instead of 5000
function myCallback() {
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours();
var showMe = today.getHours() == 12; // time when you wanna show
var element = document.getElementById("chat-box");
if(showMe){
 element.style.display = "block";  
 } else {
   element.style.display = "none";  
 }

console.log("date", date);
console.log("time", time);
console.log("showMe", showMe);
```

}

In HTML:

```
<div class="chat" id="chat-box"> // add ID to this div
```

Changes in your pen:
https://codepen.io/haji/pen/ExxBPqZ

Answer (score 0):

```
we you can use set interval function in js.

for example

setInterval(function() {

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date("January 19, 2116 17:59:00")

// check the time in if condition  
if (current.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) {
    // add some class to hide your chat bot
  } else if (current.getTime() < expiry.getTime()) {
    // add some class to show your chat bot
  }

}, 0);
```

Comment: What happens on 19 Jan 2116?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Saima Haji, you can use the ***window.setInterval*** function. it's always a good practice to create a CSS class and add it to your HTML element which is to be hidden.

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

give an id to you chatbot div, to fetch it using JS and manipulate its properties.

```
<div id="chatbot">Chatbot HTML</div>
```

finally, the JS code with ***setInterval*** function which is called on every delay that you specify as the second argument in the function as shown in the code snippet, here I have used 500ms delay, the ***now.getHours()*** does the trick of fetching the time in hours. next, you should check the desired time period.

```js
let chatbot = document.getElementById("chatbot");
setInterval(function() {
    let now = new Date();
    let thisHour = now.getHours();
    if(thisHour >= 8 && thisHour <= 16) {
        chatbot.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    else{
        chatbot.classList.add("hide");
    }
}, 500)
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbot">Chatbot HTML</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why did you use 500 ms delay?

Comment: using 0 as delay would be an overkill for the requirement, while anything above 500ms would make it from little to highly noticeable for the user.

Comment: @Vipul Dessai if checking every 500 ms, does it not burden the website? seems to make the website performance slow

Comment: @Vipul Dessai You are not check timezone? I'm afraid of the wrong timezone